# Batch para localizar serviço com caractere especial

Tags: windows, batch

Estou tentando fazer uma bat para ligar um serviço do Windows que possui caracter especial "Ç", porém não consegui chegar em nenhum código viável. Sempre me retorna o erro 1060.

Essa é mais ou menos a estrutura da minha bat:

```
SC QUERY "Serviço Bonjour" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO MISSING_BONJOUR
ECHO Configurando AutoStart do Bonjour...
sc config "serviço do bonjour" start=auto
sc start "serviço do bonjour"
GOTO END
```

No exemplo acima já tentei diversos outros mecanismos, inclusive o de substring, mas não tive sucesso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme seu comando você está pegando pelo "**NOME_PARA_EXIBIÇÃO**", porém se você pegar pelo "**NOME_DO_SERVIÇO**" não terá problemas.

**Exemplo:**

**NOME_DO_SERVIÇO:** DPS

**NOME_PARA_EXIBIÇÃO:** Servi**ç**o de Diretiva de Diagn**ó**stico

Assim resultando o comando abaixo para iniciar o serviço:

```
sc config "DPS" start=auto
sc start "DPS"
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso!

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez precisei fazer um bat para configura placa de rede, não manjo nada, mas copio bem hehe.
Tive problema com acentuação e descobri que precisa trocar esses caracteres por outro, segue uma lista.
O caminho é esse.

> Citação
>
> á=

à=…

ã=Æ

ä=„

â=ƒ

Á=µ

À=·

Ã=Ç

Ä=Ž

Â=¶

é=‚

è=Š

ë=‰

ê=ˆ

É=

È=Ô

Ë=Ó

Ê=Ò

í=¡

ì=

ï=‹

î=Œ

Í=Ö

Ì=Þ

Ï=Ø

Î=×

ó=¢

ò=•

õ=ä

ö=”

ô=“

Ó=à

Ò=ã

Õ=å

Ö=™

Ô=â

ú=£

ù=—

ü=

û=–

Ú=é

Ù=ë

Ü=š

Û=ê

ç=‡

Ç=€

§=õ

¹=û

²=ý

³=ü

£=œ

¢=½

¬=ª

º=§

ª=¦

º=ø

> Citação